# PHP database call

Tags: php, dynamic-data

I am very new to PHP and am trying to find the best solution to my problem. In my database I have a field "painters". Within painters I have "painter A", "Painter B",and "Painter C". Is their a way to display painter c if certain art work comes up? Or Painter "B", if a certain art work comes up? I am trying to understand the best way to do something like this dynamically. Any links, code, or tutorials would help me tremendously!
Thanks so much in advance!

-Mike

Comment: try google `beginner php mysql tutorial`

Comment: Well I think thats what I am asking. I am trying to find out the best thing to research to get my answer. This is part of my research :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want 3 tables.  A "Painters" table, a "assoc" table, and a "Painting" table.

Painters table includes:

- ID
- Name
- DOB
- Phone
- Address
- Blah
- blah

Painting table includes:

- ID
- Name
- Date_Created
- Blah
- Blah
- Blah

Assoc table links them...  It looks like:

- ID
- PAINTER_ID
- PAINTING_ID

So you can say SELECT PAINTING_ID FROM 'ASSOC' WHERE PAINTER_ID = '$Your_variable'
Then with that result set iterate through that array with a foreach.

Inside that foreach: you will
SELECT * FROM PAINTINGS WHERE ID = Array['PAINTING_ID'].

That's a basic associative relational database.

You can google more about it, but that's the basics that should get you started

Comment: Thanks very much for the example, it really helps me grab a better understanding of it.

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading these W3 tutorials.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

If you are like me and you need a visual aid then watch this tutorial, without this guy I wouldn't know anything about PHP, and I wouldn't have been able to creat my own CMS software, which I use for many of my clients.

For some reason the link won't post so Google "build a cms php youtube" and then click on the first video result :)

In future, it is good to try it yourself, and when you stumble upon problems, post on Stack Overflow,  your question was a little to vague here.

Comment: Hey Mr.Stuart, sorry would you mind re-posting that you tube link, I think its broken.