# Need help choosing how to building my database

Tags: database

I'm building a database that contains for each customer's purchase
Product Name
Product Manufacturer
Store
Date
Buyer's name
Buyer company
Some data such as product name, manufacturer, shop, buyer's name and the buyer's company back on themselves at the time.
Is it better to build them in separate tables and in the primary table to keep their indexes?
On the one hand it saves space on the server
On the other hand it overloads the server and requires more work

Comment: I would make a relational database that has associative tables.  For instance for each customer's purchase: Select Product_Index from 'Products_to_Customer' WHERE customer ID = "customer_id"  --  Then I would take those, and foreach Product_Index in array: Select * From Product_Table where id = 'Product_Index'.  Product table would contain these fields: Name Manufacturer etc ...    You would repeat these associations for every different table.  The structure can be found in this answer I made on a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585964/php-database-call/11586092#11586092

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep buyer information and product information in separate tables. There is no reason to store this information more then once.

In addition you could use a (relation like) table with buyer id, serialized array of product id's and date of the purchase.

```
buyer_id | {"prod1_id","prod2_id",...} | date
```

This way you get a table with all purchases that you can get whenever you want. This will increase the calls to the database but save on the storage.

Hope it makes sense to you.